# Esperar por uma wifi específica?

Tags: android

Criei o seguinte teste, buscando o nome da WIFI e o MACADDRESS de quem me envia esta WIFI.

Gostaria de ficar "escutando" se existe uma WIFI especifica, para que ao achá-la, fazer alguma coisa.

Como fazer isso?

Segue abaixo o código que estou utilizando:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Solicita as permissões
        String[] permissoes = new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
        };
        PermissionUtils.validate(this, 0, permissoes);

        //Getting the connection info
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        //Access point's MAC address
        String bssid = wifiInfo.getBSSID();
        String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();

        TextView wifi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifi);
        TextView mac = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mac);

        if (bssid != null) {
            mac.setText(bssid);
        }

        if (ssid != null && ssid.equals("specific wifi")) {
            doSomething();
            wifi.setText(wifiInfo.getSSID());
        }
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        //TODO something
    }

    protected Context getContext(){
        return this;
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.bob.getwifitest2">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Isso é uma beleza pra segurança. Essa é a forma mais usada pra folgar nos celulares alheios. É tudo o que o *hacker* deseja, um aparelho que confie totalmente em um wifi honeypot :)

Comment: @bigown opa, valeu a dica. Mas o uso completo não está aí. Somente preciso saber quando uma wifi especifica aparecer. Obrigado!